# prove by epislon delta (a hard question)

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x) , g(x)$ two functions defined at $x=0$

and :

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} = 0$$

prove that :

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$$

Comment: denote $h=\frac{f}{g}$ to make the calculations easier

Comment: @shaihorowitz: "square root method"? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 4):

$$\left| \dfrac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} - 0 \right| = \left| \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} - 0 \right|$$

${}$

Therefore if $\left| \dfrac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} - 0 \right| < \varepsilon$ then $\left| \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} - 0 \right| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Worth pointing is that the quotient here is red herring -- it's enough to prove that whenever $\lim |f(x)| = 0$, we also have $\lim f(x) = 0$.